# How can I download zip to python directory from google storage after obtaing response object?

Tags: python

After running the following code successfully, I think I am close to get access to the zip file in gcloud storage. However, I really cannot figure out what to do next, download or something to make the zip file available for python environment as a programmable object.

```py
from gs import GSClient
client = GSClient()
object_meta = client.get("b/rcmikejupyter/o/output1.zip")
with client.get("b/rcmikejupyter/o/output1.zip", params=dict(alt="media"), stream=True) as res:
    object_bytes = res.raw.read()
```

Comment: If `object_bytes = res.raw.read()` get the raw bytes, you may try to save it to a local file: `open('output1.zip', 'wb').write(object_bytes)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming this is a byesobject

```
with open("pathto/yourfile.zip", "wb") as file:
    file.write(object_bytes)
```

Comment: Thanks for your solution. I will try it.